# White screen at app startup - Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

I created a **splash screen** for my application using an **empty activity** that stays **visible** for 3 seconds with a background image.
Usually, the application starts with a white screen before the background image becomes visible, however, some applications are already started with the "real" splash screen image.
How to **implement** this?

Comment: Remove your splash screen they cause a ton of problems and provide little to no value to your users.

Comment: where you set your background image?

Comment: JakeWilson801  then should I start the application through the login screen, or if the user is already logged in, do I start by the restricted area?

Comment: JakeWilson801  but if I do not have a login screen? Is not it necessary to splash screen?

Comment: HassanUsman I used android:background=" " in Relative Layout

Comment: Plenty of apps use splash screens (Facebook, Snapchat, etc.). It's subjective on a UX level.

Answer (score 4):

you can use splash screen in this way.

1. Add style for splash screen activity in styles.xml

   ```
   <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/yourImageName</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Add that style as theme to your SplashScreenActivity in manifest file

   ```
   <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
       android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
3. Remove setContentView() in SplashScreenActivity's onCreate() Method and use it as a java file which extends AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because system process draws initial blank screen when launching the app, from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html#themed):

> A common way to implement a themed launch screen is to use the **windowDisablePreview** theme attribute to turn off the initial blank
>   screen that the system process draws when launching the app. However,
>   this approach can result in a longer startup time than apps that don’t
>   suppress the preview window. Also, it forces the user to wait with no
>   feedback while the activity launches, making them wonder if the app is
>   functioning properly.

You can disable it with [windowDisablePreview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowDisablePreview) attribute, something like this:

```
  <application
      ...
      android:windowDisablePreview="true">
   ...
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Splash Activity usually starts with the background.
Try this code, it might help you.

Code for your splash activity page.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

Thread myThread = new Thread(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(3000);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
    myThread.start();
}}
```

In layout file, you need to include just Image which you want to see on the splash page.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/capture"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And make sure you add the Splashscreen page before Main activity in Manifest.

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
```